# Spring Data - Loading JSON file to create multiple tables

Tags: spring-data-jpa

Suppose I have a JSON File(sample.json) for Persons showing the Cars they owned. I am trying to load this file into database, but I want to create two tables - PERSON and CAR. I have had limited success. I am using Spring Boot Data JPA and I am able to insert all the rows, but somehow the OneToMany mapping between 'Person & Cars' is not reflecting because the CAR.person_id column is null. What should I do to get this column correctly populated with person_id.

```
[
    {
        "name": "Robert",
        "cars_owned": [
            {
                "brand": "Mercedes",
                "model": "SLX 500"
            },
            {
                "brand": "Jaguar",
                "model": "ZL 300F"
            },
            {
                "brand": "Mercedes",
                "model": "CLS 350"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Brenda",
        "cars_owned": [
            {
                "brand": "Honda",
                "model": "Accord"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Edward"
    }
]
```

Here is my Person.java

```
@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "uuid4")
    private UUID person_id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Car> cars_owned;
    
    public UUID getPerson_id() {
        return person_id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setCars_owned(List<Car> cars_owned) {
        this.cars_owned = cars_owned;
    }
}
```

This is my Car.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cars")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Car {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "uuid4")
    private UUID car_id;

    private String brand;
    private String model;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
    private Person person;

    public UUID getCar_id() {
        return car_id;
    }

    public String getBrand() {
        return brand;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setPerson(Person person) {
        this.person = person;
    }
}
```

I am using a CommanLineRunner like this.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TryAppApplication {
    private final static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TryAppApplication.class);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TryAppApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner runner(PersonService service) {
        return args -> {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            TypeReference<List<Person>> typeReference = new TypeReference<>() { };
            InputStream inputStream = TypeReference.class.getResourceAsStream("/json/sample.json");

            try {
                List<Person> persons = mapper.readValue(inputStream, typeReference);
                service.save(persons);
                LOGGER.info("Saved Persons");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //TODO: handle exception
            }
        };
    }
}
```

The program does insert 3 Persons and 4 Cars, but the Cars.person_id column is null! I want it to be the correct person_id. Any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it with a hack! I am not so happy about it as I think there might be definitely a better solution than this.

I have basically modified my PersonService.save() function as below

PersonService.java

```
public Iterable<Person> save(Iterable<Person> pList) {
        for (Person person : pList) {
            person.linkCarsToPerson(); // This function in Person class links Car and Person
        }
        System.out.println(pList);
        return repository.saveAll(pList);
    }
```

PersonModel.java

```
public void linkCarsToPerson() {
        if (cars_owned != null && !cars_owned.isEmpty()) {
            for (Car car : cars_owned) {
                if(car != null) {
                    car.setPerson(this);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```